# How to use Bootstrap npm package with React

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, reactjs

I have a meteor application which uses react at the front-end. I have installed bootstrap using npm (not atmospherejs), and I'm having trouble using the bootstrap styles in my react component. Here's the code for my main component.

```
import React from 'react';

import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

const Layout = ({content = () => null }) => (

  <div>
   <div className="row">
     <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
     <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>      
     <div className="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
     <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
   </div>
  </div>  
);

export default Layout;
```

I'm new to react. Can someone tell me what's missing here and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The styles are defined in CSS. You're importing the JavaScript.

Comment: Are you using systemjs or webpack?

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski it's meteor so I don't have to use a bundling package right?

Comment: So what's the correct way to use it?

Comment: @ThaiTran I'm using a [stateless component](https://toddmotto.com/stateless-react-components/) here. That's why I don't have the React.createClass.

Comment: @TA3: ok, thanks. i didn't realize about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known problem with Meteor. So I guess I'll have to depend on alternatives until MDG find a solution.

[Style files imports from node_modules](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6037)

Comment: Please include relevant parts in the answer itself, this will prevent the answer from link rot.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to import Bootstrap's CSS to use the appropriate classes in your component. This [can be done with Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html):

### installation

Install the loaders from npm.

```
npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev
```

### configuration

Here is a configuration example that enables require() css:

```
{
    // ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ]
    }
}
```

### using css

```
// in your modules just require the stylesheet
// This has the side effect that a <style>-tag is added to the DOM.
require("./stylesheet.css");

// or
// import "./stylesheet.css";
```

Comment: Since I'm using meteor, I don't think there's a point using a bundling tool like Webpack, am I correct @Pavlo?